# C# Creating a ListBox with icons

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, listbox

Could anyone give me any sugguestions on how I could create a list box with icons or point me to a tutorial?

Here's my program:[image: GUI]

I use a query to load friends email and name from a database into a list box data source.

Code:

```
public void LoadUserData(ListBox FriendsLb)
{
    var query = from o in Globals.DB.Friends
                where o.UserEmail == Properties.Settings.Default.Email
                select new
                {
                    FirstName = o.FirstName,
                    LastName = o.LastName,
                    Email = o.Email,
                    Display = string.Format("{0} {1} - ({2})", o.FirstName, o.LastName, o.Email)
                };
    FriendsLb.DataSource = query.ToList();
    FriendsLb.ClearSelected();
}
```

I want it to load like: `[Avatar] Firstname, LastName - (Email)`

Comment: Use a ListView instead!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately ListView doesn't support data source or display and value members! :(

Comment: That's right. Have you considered owner-drawing the ListBox?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd385906(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Meth: This is about a winforms ListView and it really is very bad at databinding. Ownerdrawing the ListBox is a snap in comparison!

Comment: Where shall the images come from?

Comment: got cha.. not a problem

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten to accept your answer my apologies. You have pointed me in the right direction with an owner drawn list box :-). Just having a few problems updating current items in the list box. Thanks !

Comment: What kind of problems? Maybe I can help..?

Comment: Do you do freelance?

Comment: Nope, just here for the fun of it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of **ownerdrawing** the `ListBox`.

```
private void FriendsLb_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    Bitmap bmp = someBitmap;
    bmp.SetResolution(e.Graphics.DpiX, e.Graphics.DpiY);
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(yourItemText, someFont, Brushes.Black, 
                          bmp.Width + 5, e.Bounds.Y);  // adapt to you liking

    if (bmp != null)
    {
        FriendsLb.ItemHeight = bmp.Height;  // or a little more..
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, e.Bounds.Y);
    }

}
```

Set the `ListBox.DrawMode` to `OnwerDrawFixed`.

The `ListBox.ItemHeight` actually could (and should) be set in advance. Note that only **one** size is allowed for all `Items`!

Of course you wil need to get at the right data. Since the `Items` are bound to your `DataSource` the `e.Index` should point to the right row. So you should be able to pull out the name or the display string; you also will need to get at the image; I don't see you reading it in, so it is up to you to solve that problem..

If they sit in an `ImageList` you can easily pull out the right one, if the indices are in synch; or you can use the `Keys` property. With `Imagelist` the size of all images is fixed anyway, so you can set the `ItemHeight` in advance..

Note that I set the dpi resolution of the bitmap the the one of the current screen.

Instead of the default `DrawBackground()` call you may want to to a `FillRectangle` with nicer Colors, depending on the `e.State`..

Comment: How do you get the image though?

Comment: Well you wrote they are in an imagelist, right? Depending how you have added them this could be good enough: `Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)yourImageList.Images[e.Index];`

Comment: Sorry, never done anything like this before... How would I create a rectangle around the avatar and string as I would need to click on the friends? Thanks

Comment: `Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
            rect.Inflate(0, -1);

            if (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected))
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);`

Comment: Works fine. Where did you put it? Should be at the end, or least __after the `DrawBackground`__. - I personally would prefer to pick a nice background color depening on the same condtion and created by a FillRectangle..

Comment: @richardj97 Did you test it? What error do you received or what was the problem. The answer contains anything you need to know about  an owner-draw list box. Also based on your next questions it seems you could apply such solution.